# Meteor exception in Meteor.flush when updating a collection breaks reactivity across clients

Tags: node.js, meteor

When I'm calling Collection.update from the front end (the method call is allowed), the update does work ok, but the exception below is being thrown (in Chrome's JS console, not in the server). Although the update took place, other clients connected to the same collection do not see the updates until they refresh the browser - I suspect because of the exception.

Any idea what might cause this?

```
Exception from Meteor.flush: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch
    at Object.Spark.createLandmark (http://checkadoo.com/packages/spark/spark.js?8b4e0abcbf865e6ad778592160ec3b3401d7abd2:1085:13)
    at http://checkadoo.com/packages/templating/deftemplate.js?7f4bb363e9e340dbaaea8d74ac670af40ac82d0a:115:26
    at Object.Spark.labelBranch (http://checkadoo.com/packages/spark/spark.js?8b4e0abcbf865e6ad778592160ec3b3401d7abd2:1030:14)
    at Object.partial [as list_item] (http://checkadoo.com/packages/templating/deftemplate.js?7f4bb363e9e340dbaaea8d74ac670af40ac82d0a:114:24)
    at http://checkadoo.com/packages/handlebars/evaluate.js?ab265dbab665c32cfd7ec343166437f2e03f1a54:349:48
    at Object.Spark.labelBranch (http://checkadoo.com/packages/spark/spark.js?8b4e0abcbf865e6ad778592160ec3b3401d7abd2:1030:14)
    at branch (http://checkadoo.com/packages/handlebars/evaluate.js?ab265dbab665c32cfd7ec343166437f2e03f1a54:308:20)
    at http://checkadoo.com/packages/handlebars/evaluate.js?ab265dbab665c32cfd7ec343166437f2e03f1a54:348:20
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://checkadoo.com/packages/underscore/underscore.js?772b2587aa2fa345fb760eff9ebe5acd97937243:76:11)
```

**EDIT 2**

The error will also occur if the update call is run in the console. It happens on the first run of the update but by then reactivity is broken on any other browser attached to it.

**EDIT**
Here is my template for the clickable item that triggers the update:

```
<template name="list_item">
  <li class="checklistitemli">
  <div class="{{checkbox_class}}" id="clitem_{{index}}">
    <input type="checkbox" name="item_checked" value="1" id="clcheck_{{index}}" class="checklist_item_check" {{checkbox_ticked}}> {{title}}
  </div>
  </li>
</template>
```

and here's the event handler for clicks on 'list_item':

```
Template.list_item.events = {
  'click .checklistitem' : function(ev) {
    this.checked = !this.checked; 
    var updateItem = {}; 
    updateItem['items.'+this.index+'.checked'] = this.checked; 
    console.log("The error happens here");
    Lists.update({_id: this._id}, {$set:updateItem}, {multi:false} , function(err) { 
      console.log("In callback, after the error"); 
    });
  }
}
```

The whole thing is available at http://checkadoo.com (Its a port of a Tornado based Python app of mine)

Comment: Maybe show us how you are rendering the collection that is being updated?

Comment: Added some code example.

Comment: There's a lot going on here; can you simply it down to something that displays the same error?

Comment: I simplified the example. Also the error will occur if you just submit the update call via the console without any event handler. It comes from sparks, but triggered from the update call (i.e., data changes).

Comment: I take it's not the lack of closing `</input>` that's the problem?

Comment: Any chance of making a simple github project that demonstrates the bug, like they ask here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki

Comment: Tom, the whole thing is available at http://checkadoo.com. Click on any of the public lists, open a console and until one of the items. You can also paste the update code into the console and get the same error without any event involved. If you look at the console I left an easy copy/paste line to trigger the error for the selected checklist item by pasting it into console without depending on the event.

And no, i'm afraid its not the closing input.... This has been driving me crazy for days now.

Comment: The problem is that it's really hard to diagnose problems like this without code that causes the problem running on your machine. If you can create a really simple new project that has the problem and check it into github, it would make it much easier to try and fix.

Comment: I'll do my best Tom. I've already decided to start it from scratch. I really wanted to run a meteor mini project, so I might as well put in the milage. Thanks!

Comment: I am having trouble seeing the problem now. I added a public list and no luck in seeing an error in my console.

Comment: its still there though it happens only after the first check. The user in the browser won't necessarily notice but any other mobile device that has the same list open won't get the check update. From that point reactivity across different clients on the same data is broken.

Comment: Based on my vague understanding of this issue (it's related to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/281) I think it'll be hard to help this without also seeing the context where `list_item` itself is invoked.

Comment: Harel, Are you still having this issue? Do you have a Github repo we could look at? I'm going through the Meteor questions and wondering which ones are actually still open :-).

Comment: Hi cmather. Yes I still have that issue with the latest meteor. I don't have a git repo for this I'm afraid. I will try to find the time to redo this app from scratch and see where exactly I go wrong. At the moment meteor seems very interesting and promising but not production ready (mostly due to problems like that where I don't even know where to begin looking at them). Thanks for the comment though.

Comment: I am also having this problem. There is a simple app the exhibits it here: https://gist.github.com/drew-gross/6202629 to reproduce, create a tab on the console with `Tabs.insert({owner:"foo"})` then visit `localhost:3000/tabs/:id` then click the 'buy one' button

Comment: Might be dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494390/metor-blade-template-throws-second-landmark-in-same-branch-exception-in-for-lo

Comment: Geez just noticed the name of the OP - it's a small world Harel :D

Answer (score 0):

I've found this is usually an issue with duplicate ids.  @Harel's question doesn't include the code that actually renders the collection so we can't tell the root cause of his problem but the repro that @Drew supplied in the comments is throwing this error because it is rendering an array of objects that have duplicate '_id' values.

I have put together a working version of @Drew's repro:
  https://github.com/alanning/meteor-buggy-fix

The key fix is to ensure the inserted drink items do not have duplicate '_id' fields:

```
  Template.drink_from_menu.events({
    'click .buy_drink': function () {
      var drink = {name: this.name, price: this.price};

      console.log("this = ", this);

      // using 'this' doesn't work because it already has a '_id' field and 
      // you would be trying to render multiple drinks with the same id
      // which causes Spark to throw the "Can't create second landmark 
      // in same branch" error
      //Tabs.update({_id:Session.get('tabId')}, {$push: {ordered_drinks: this}});

      // either ensure that the objects you want Spark to render have a 
      // unique id or leave off the _id completely and let Spark do it for you
      Tabs.update({_id:Session.get('tabId')}, {$push: {ordered_drinks: drink}});
    }
  });
```