# metor blade template throws "second landmark in same branch" exception in for loop

Tags: meteor, laravel-blade, meteorite, node-blade

I have a for loop that I want to include a template view in:

table.blade:

```
#game
    h1= table.name 
        -if( table.playerSitting() )
            a.btn.btn-danger.stand(href="#") Stand
    #table
        -for (var i=0; i<7;i++)
            include 'seat' exposing i
```

seat.blade:

```
- id = 'p' + (i+1)
    div(id="#{id}")
        -if (table.hasAt(i))
            p= table.usernameAt(i)
        -else
            -if( !table.playerSitting() )
                a.btn.btn-inverse.sit(href="#", data-key="#{i}") Sit
            -else
                p &nbsp;
```

When I first load the view, everything draws fine.  But if I sit or stand, or go to another table, I get this:

```
Exception from Deps recompute: Error: Can't create second landmark in same branch
    at /home/thomporter/meteor/blackjack/views/table.blade:8:4

 6 |        #table
 7 |            -for (var i=0; i<7;i++)
 8 >                include 'seat' exposing i
 9 |    
10 |
```

I figure I can fix this by creating a "seats" collection that stores the user id & table ids, but that seems silly.  I'm currently using an array property of the table called "players", index 0-6 for each seat...  at least, that's the idea. =)

I should also mention I replaced seat.blade with:

```
p hi
```

and no luck, same issues.

Any ideas?

**Edit**
Version Information:
Meteorite version 0.4.9
Meteor version 0.5.9 (git checkout)
Blade 3.0.3

Comment: I must ask... what version of Meteor are you running?  What version of Blade?  And, does `table.blade` or any parent templates contain [block declarations](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade#blocks)?  Also, I should mention that you may want to create an issue here: https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues

Comment: I'm using Meteorite version 0.4.9 & Meteor version 0.5.9.  Blade is 3.0.3 according to it's package.json in my ~/.meteorite folder...

Comment: Also, no blocks in templates... all plain .blade files in views/...

Comment: I was able to duplicate this bug. I will add this to the Blade issue tracker and get it resolved soon! Thanks for your post!

Comment: Have a looko at https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/281 - it was/still is a known issue with a workaround in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug is actually a result of using plain-old for loops instead of `foreach` loops.

> The foreach region is preferred over ... [regular for loops] not only
>   because of readability and brevity, but because it also provides Blade
>   with the ability to better integrate with live page updating engines
>   (specifically Meteor and Spark). That is, if the live page update
>   engine supports tracking reactive collections, the most efficient DOM
>   operations may occur to update the view's results in-place, without
>   re-rendering the entire Blade template.

In your case, Spark is failing to re-render your included templates because of matching branches for the same landmark.  If you use `foreach`, this problem is resolved.

However, in some situations (like yours), `foreach` is not appropriate.  I think that the solution here is to create a "regular for loop" syntax within Blade to handle loops.  Because of this, I created [issue # 157](https://github.com/bminer/node-blade/issues/157).